# Debian 8 no reconoce más de 16 GB en USB

Tags: debian

Instalé *Debian 8* en un **USB de 32 GB**. Una vez que *Debian* estaba funcionando, intenté instalar *openVAS* pero antes de terminar la instalación, un mensaje me advirtió que ya no había suficiente espacio. Revisando el dispositivo *USB (LaCle 32 GB)* vi que había más de **16 GB libres**. ¿Es que *Debian*, no puede reconocer todos los *32 GBs*? O, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los reconozca?

Comment: Indica con qué programa creaste tu USB bootable. Si lo hiciste de solo lectura o no permites el almacenamiento persistente, no puedes instalar nada. Usa este enlace para __[edit]__.

Comment: ¿Cuanto espacio le asignaste a cada partición (`/`, `/bin`, etc) ...?

Answer (score 0):

Primero quita todas las particiones del pendrive. Hay herramientas para hacerlo con windows, con linux es mas facil, utiliza el comando fdisk

Una vez que está vacio, ninguna particion, empieza a instalar y cuando empiece la parte del particionado comprueba que tienes 28G, y los coges todos.